# Recalculate height function working once in a while

Tags: jquery, css, resize, load, height

I've got some troubles with script which is reading height of the div, and then resizing other one.

Basically it is doing it only once in a while.

It seems to me, that function is geting the div's height before all elements are actually loaded.

```
function recalculate_h() {
    if ($(".content_full").is(":visible")){
           var cur = $(".content_full").height()+100;
             animate_height(cur);

       }
}

function smooth_change(way) {
 // rest of the code
    $("#here").load("index.php?siteno="+next+" #there", function(evt) {

        $("#outer").attr("siteno", next);    
            recalculate_h(); 
    });
}
```

And it is called within document.ready

```
$(".left_navigator").click(function() {
        smooth_change("back");
});
```

Any ideas what I've might done wrong?

P.S.

There are two ways of navigating the site, through basic refresh and GET attributes, and smoother using ajax request.
Plus, recalculate_h is called on each page load like this, and this is working perfectly.

```
$(window).load(function() {

     recalculate_h();
     //$('#map_canvas').gmap();
```

});

Comment: please add as a jsfiddle as there is no way for us to know what 'next' is or whether the jquery load is every returning from the server

Comment: Do you have any images in page you are loading?

Comment: Yes, there are some. My first guess was, that it could be cause of css positioning... but as I wrote before, this is actually working. Sometimes it's doing it right, sometimes it seems forget about some divs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using jquery ajax call to load index.php?siteno.... and call recalculate_h(); on complete event of ajax?

I see that you are setting these values incorrectly:

```
var middle_banner_height = 100;
var middle_banner_width = 802;
```

You should set them like this:

```
var middle_banner_height = "100px";
var middle_banner_width = "802px";
```

Plus in this call you set midle_banner_with instead of middle_banner_width so you get midle_banner_with is not defined.
Anyhow this maybe want solve the whole bug, but your script is breaking here.

Comment: Isn't `.load` a short form of `.ajax()`? And he is already calling `recalculate_h()` in complete function..."

Comment: Oh, yes. Didn't notice that. I used css after all and totally forgot about remnants in index, thanks. Btw. although misstyped, this piece of code does basically nothing now.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same scenario in one of my projects before and the way I solved it is by grabbing the elements you want to resize and set its css to height: auto. Then add the rest of the code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I've wrapped all in one div with css:auto, but it didn't change much. If you'd like to take a look, here is the actual project http://dditorkney.com/beta/index.php btw. If you'll navigate with arrows in the middle banner it's only the matter of time when it'll crash.

Comment: Since I've tried allready many things, I set finally css height to fixed value. It's actually the worst solution, but it's working for now.